# Pull SVN Changelist from another server?

Tags: svn, changelist

Just curious about this, I have one server our dev where a ridiculous amount of changes have been made, then another server that I need to push JUST those changes, and of course a repository in the middle.

I have managed to pretty much kern out the files I want from our Dev and put them in a changelist, I'd like to pull only those files on our other server, but since the changelist
doesn't migrate, its kind of a pita.

I was wondering if there's a solution to this, currently i'm thinking of doing something like

```
$ svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD . > update.log
# edit out what I don't want by hand =(
$ svn up `cat update.log`
# cross fingers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question.

If you need to just get the changes introduced by a range of commits, just do `svn diff -rN:M` on the server, get the resulting patch to the local machine, and run `svn patch` (or just `patch`--it's hard to understand what you really want to do) to apply the changes.

If, instead, you have an (outdated) local copy of the same subversion repository and thinking about how to bring it in sync with the remote one, then [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html) should be the way to go, or even good old `rsync` if you can guarantee that the remote repo won't be written to while synchronising.

Comment: I think the answer might be forking each time a new project hits and merging that later on. We have around 6 projects worth or random commits here, its hard to tell what goes to what project....